# Renaming Alphanumeric images with PHP

Tags: php

I have almost 10,000 images in a Folder with image name like

**Abies_koreana_Blauer_Pfiff_05-06-10_1.jpg 

Abies_koreana_Prostrate_Beauty_05-05-10_2.jpg

Chamaecyparis_obtusa_Limerick 06-10-10_3.jpg

Fagus_sylvatica_Dawyck_Gold_05-02-10_1.jpg**

What i want do is rename the images using PHP so that only the characters remain in the image name want to delete the Numeric part so for example the above images would look like

**Abies_koreana_Blauer_Pfiff.jpg

Abies_koreana_Prostrate_Beauty.jpg

Chamaecyparis_obtusa_Limerick.jpg

Fagus_sylvatica_Dawyck_Gold.jpg**

Is this possible ? Or i have to do it manually ?

Comment: have a look at [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: You dont want to strip the numeric part, in your samples you treat - and _ as numbers. Do you want to strip everything after the first number?

Comment: I want to strip the Numeric part as well as - & _ before and after the  Numbers

Comment: So, if it are always 11 characters to remove, substr($filename, 0, -11) should to the trick.

Comment: I think what you mean is i shall find "." first and then from right to left remove 12 characters right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreach file name do this

```
$new_filename = preg_replace("/(\w\d{0,2}[\W]{1}.+\.)/",".",$current_file_name);
```

so final function may look like this

```
function renameFiles($directory) 
{

$handler = opendir($directory);
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

  if(preg_match("/(\w\d{0,2}[\W]{1}.+\.)/",$file)) {
    echo $file."<br/>";  
  }
rename($directory."/".$file,$directory."/".preg_replace("/(\w\d{0,2}[\W]{1}.+\.)/",".",$file));
}
}
closedir($handler);
}

renameFiles("c:/wserver");
```

**Updated**

Comment: It says"Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: No ending delimiter '/' found in test1.php on line 16 that is where the code is located 
 $new_filename = preg_replace("/(\w\d{0,2}[\W]{1}.+\.)",".",$file);

Comment: oh sorry! missed / at the end. Typing directly into an editor is sometimes not that great idea :)

Comment: ok let me test this function for you. will be back with edits if required.

Comment: Edited again try to use the function as it it and replace path to your folder/directory in function call

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PHP (or bash).
Your friends are [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/recursivedirectoryiterator) to walk through directories, [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace) to modify the file names, [rename()](http://php.net/rename) to reflect changed filename on disk.

What you're trying to do can be done in ~10 lines of code. Using the ingredients above, you should be able to write a little script to change filenames yourself.

**Update**

throwing out the numeric parts (according to the examples given) can be done with a rather simple regular expression. Note that this will remove any numbers (-_ ) between the [a-z] filename and the suffix (".jpq"). So you won't get "foo3.png" but "foo.png". If this is a problem, the regex can be adjusted to meet that criteria…

```
<?php

$files = array(
    'Abies_koreana_Blauer_Pfiff_05-06-10_1.jpg',
    'Abies_koreana_Prostrate_Beauty_05-05-10_2.jpg',
    'Chamaecyparis_obtusa_Limerick 06-10-10_3.jpg',
    'Fagus_sylvatica_Dawyck_Gold_05-02-10_1.jpg',
);

foreach ($files as $source) {
    // strip all numeric (date, counts, whatever) 
    // characters before the file's suffix
    // (?= …) is a non-capturing look-ahead assertion
    // see http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php for more info
    $destination = preg_replace('#[ _0-9-]+(?=\.[a-z]+$)#i', '', $source);
    echo "'$source' to '$destination'\n";
}
```

Comment: I can write that code not a big deal, problem is how to differentiate between Alphanumeric

Comment: added a regex to rename your files…